# When CSS is gzipped it doesn't work

Tags: css, gzip

I my css stylesheet that i want to gzip. I have it linked as a external stylesheet. 
Here: http://illution.dk
And this is the stylesheet: http://illution.dk/include/style.css
And it IS gzipped: http://www.whatsmyip.org/http_compression/?url=aHR0cDovL2lsbHV0aW9uLmRrL2luY2x1ZGUvc3R5bGUuY3Nz

My problem is that it doesn't seem to work. Am i doing something wrong?

**UPDATE:** I found out that i just needed to add "header("Content-type: text/css"); " to my css document and it just worked :D!

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to your own question and/or accept an answer. It will help people know that this is resolved. I feel like I just wasted 2 minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSS appears to be valid as I checked here: [W3C CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fillution.dk%2Finclude%2Fstyle.css&profile=css21&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en) and it looks right for me on Chrome. However, I did see a warning in the Chrome Developer tools:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html.
```

It appears your server isn't properly setting the MIME type for CSS files.